# How to convert hex to Color(RGBA) with TryParseHtmlString

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, colors

How can I change the button color in Unity, using HEX values?
I tried this, but it doesn't work, perhaps I made a mistake here:

```
btn.image.color = ColorUtility.TryParseHtmlString(DADADAFF, out color);
```

Comment: What's the problem? What happens? Did you read the error?

Comment: @SLaks "does not exist in the current contest".

Comment: As it's trying to toll you,  there is no such variable.  You want a string.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You are assigning bool to Color(`btn.image.color`).

`ColorUtility.TryParseHtmlString` returns `bool` not `Color` if successful. You get the output color in the second parameter then take that and assign it to the `Button`. Only use the output color if `ColorUtility.TryParseHtmlString` returns true.

Below is what that code should look like:

```
string htmlValue = "#FF0000";
Button btn = GetComponent<Button>();

Color newCol;

if (ColorUtility.TryParseHtmlString(htmlValue, out newCol))
{
    btn.image.color = newCol;
}
```

---

To convert the Color back to hex:

```
Color newCol = Color.red;
string htmlValue = ColorUtility.ToHtmlStringRGBA(newCol);
```

---

> So there is no way to just assign Hex color without checking that it
>   can be converted to RGB first?

There is. Remove the `if` statement.

```
ColorUtility.TryParseHtmlString(htmlValue, out newCol);
btn.image.color = newCol;
```

Don't do this as your `Color` result may be wrong. You should handle this with the `if` statement like I did in the first code.

Comment: Thank you! So there is no way to just assign Hex color without checking that it can be converted to RGB first?

Comment: Thank you, I meant why should we create the if statement?

Comment: In my example, we are checking if the `TryParseHtmlString` **successfully** converted the `htmlValue` (#FF0000) to RGBA/Color. If it did, assign it to the Button.

Answer (score 6):

You can use hexademical numbers:

```
btn.image.color = new Color32(0xDA, 0xDA, 0xDA, 0xFF);
```